# css rotation of 2 elements with different width to remain on the same distance

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 elements that I position one of them with the offsetLeft and offsetTop of the other one. When there is no rotation they position fine, but when there is rotation they are losing their position relative to each other, because they rotate around their center. Is there a way to fix this and if there is some formula can you also explain it?
Examples:http://jsfiddle.net/9t6n8dmk/8/

```
//firstExample without rotation
<div class ="first-element" id="first-element">

</div>
<div class="second-element" id="second-element">

</div>

//secondExample with rotation
<div class ="first-element-rotation" id="first-element-rotation">

</div>
<div class="second-element-rotation" id="second-element-rotation">

</div>
let firstElement = document.getElementById("first-element");
let secondElement = document.getElementById("second-element");

secondElement.style.top = firstElement.offsetTop + "px";
secondElement.style.left = firstElement.offsetLeft + "px";


let firstElementRotation = document.getElementById("first-element-rotation");
let secondElementRotation = document.getElementById("second-element-rotation");

secondElementRotation.style.top = firstElementRotation.offsetTop + "px";
secondElementRotation.style.left = firstElementRotation.offsetLeft + "px";

.first-element{
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}
.second-element{
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position:absolute;
}

.first-element-rotation{
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top:100px;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.second-element-rotation{
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  transform: rotate(30deg);

}
```

Comment: Hello, in your example,you can reset  transform-origin http://jsfiddle.net/9t6n8dmk/9/  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: Hey, yes thank you. There is one problem for me with that solution. I am not familiar with transform-origin (I will look more into it). I have one more element that I position in the middle and when I set "transform-origin: 0 100%" it goes out of position. Is there a way to set it also with transform-origin so it doesn't move? http://jsfiddle.net/9t6n8dmk/21/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `transform-origin` property would help:

```js
let firstElement = document.getElementById("first-element");
let secondElement = document.getElementById("second-element");

secondElement.style.top = firstElement.offsetTop + "px";
secondElement.style.left = firstElement.offsetLeft + "px";


let firstElementRotation = document.getElementById("first-element-rotation");
let secondElementRotation = document.getElementById("second-element-rotation");

secondElementRotation.style.top = firstElementRotation.offsetTop + "px";
secondElementRotation.style.left = firstElementRotation.offsetLeft + "px";
```

```css
.first-element {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}

.second-element {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.first-element-rotation {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.second-element-rotation {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
//firstExample without rotation
<div class="first-element" id="first-element">

</div>
<div class="second-element" id="second-element">

</div>

//secondExample with rotation
<div class="first-element-rotation" id="first-element-rotation">

</div>
<div class="second-element-rotation" id="second-element-rotation">

</div>
```

Comment: Hello, yes thank you. There is one problem for me with that solution. I am not familiar with transform-origin (I will look more into it). I have one more element that I position in the middle and when I set "transform-origin: 0 100%" it goes out of position. Is there a way to set it also with transform-origin so it doesn't move? http://jsfiddle.net/9t6n8dmk/21/

Comment: @ivaylo, happy to help. It's not clear to me what your desired result is. Also, you can omit your JS and use CSS for positioning your elements.

Comment: When I think about it there is no solution with transform-origin with 3 elements like that. The thing is the objects are dragable so I am using JS to reposition them one with another. Thanks for the help tho.

Answer (score 0):

A solution may be to group the 2 objects together with a `<div>` element and rotate that element instead.

Comment: Yes, I upvote you, I had similiar problem with the same thing and thought of it, but I have to change many other things. I have better solution for my purpose without grouping it, but it will be idial if there is a way to do this.

Comment: @ivalo why do you need it ungrouped?